# Include one to many association in sequelize scope

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I'm using `sequelize` in my node.js app.

I have two tables: Users and Images.
User table is in a one to many relation with Images. So, each user can have one or more images.

```
       Users                         Images
+------+----------+  +------+-----------------------+--------+
|  id  |   name   |  |  id  |         url           | UserId |
+------+----------+  +------+-----------------------+--------+
| 123  | Markus   |  | 542  | https://et.ly/e2ts    | 123    |
| 456  | Thomas   |  | 731  | https://et.ly/dwas    | 123    |
+------+----------+  | 626  | https://et.ly/2w6i    | 456    |
                     +------+-----------------------+--------+
```

I would like to have a scope which when I query for one or more users I get back something like this:

```
// Users.findById(123)
{
  id: 123,
  name: 'Markus',
  images: [
    {
      id: 542,
      url: 'https://et.ly/e2ts',
    },
    {
      id: 731,
      url: 'https://et.ly/dwas',
    },
  ]
}
```

How can I do this?

I know I have to write something in the defaultScope option of my User model, but what?

The actual `Users` model is:

```
const Users = {
  name: 'Users',
  model: {
    schema: {
      id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, },
      name: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
    }
  options: {
    defaultScope: {
      // write scope here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can check the documentation [hasMany](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/associations.html#one-to-many-associations--hasmany-). Try implementing what says there, if you still having doubts update your answer and comment here so I get the notification :)

Comment: I've solved it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out how to do it (really easy to be true)

First update the model:

```
const Users = {
  name: 'Users',
  model: {
    schema: {
      id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, },
      name: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
    }
  options: {
    defaultScope: {
      include: [{
        model: Images, as: 'images' // LIKE THIS
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Then define the associations when you are defining all the models:

```
Users.hasMany(Images, { as: 'images' });
Images.belongsTo(Users);
```

That's it.